# Creating named branches as subdocuments

Tags: node.js, mongodb

User documents will have branches and these branches have names and will also function as branches.  An example document could be something like:

```
{
    name: "username",
    // trunk
    branches: {
        foo: {
            branches: {
                bar: {
                    branches: {}
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I could add a new branch to `bar` via something like

```
db.user.update({name: "foo"}, {"$set":
    {"branches.foo.branches.bar.branches.baz": {branches: {}}
})
```

Branches will also have other information that I've left off since it's not really relevant here.

My question is is it better to store the subdocuments this way, or is it better to have an additional property (the name) and search on that?  For example:

```
{
    name: "username",
    branches: [{
        name: "foo",
        branches: []
    }]
}
```

In the latter case, I'm actually not sure how I would search the subdocuments since I haven't experimented with it.

Is there any preference for storing named subdocuments as properties vs. arrays?

Comment: Have you read this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures/

Comment: Sub documents become very impractical to search as the depth increases.

Comment: @WiredPrairie the hierarchy should never grow that large (probably a maximum of 3 levels).  Every individual hierarchy is stored on a particular user which can be searched by the indexed `name`

Comment: Unless the keys are fixed for all documents, there's not a good way to search that's effective. You need to do `key: keyName`, `value: theValue` as I think you were suggesting in the latter example.

Comment: @WiredPrairie so you are saying that even if the entire path is known as in `"branches.foo.branches.bar"` that operation is slow?  I need to find the target branch by the entire path each time, so it seems like materialized paths may be the way to go.

Comment: I assume that the names of the keys aren't known until runtime, so it's slow if you want to do a search, as every document would need to be searched manually.

Comment: @WiredPrairie can you give me an example of what you mean by searched manually?

Comment: MongoDB would need to fetch every document in the collection, find the path if it exists, and then do the comparison.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44167/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-wiredprairie)